# Using protractor to find and click an anchor link

Tags: click, protractor, anchor, href

Should be simple, I am trying to click on an image link using Protractor.

```
    <a href="//safeweb.norton.com
    /a>
```

I know I'm doing it the long way.

```
    var nortonlink = element(by.css('[href="//safeweb.norton.com/"]'));

    nortonlink.click();

    expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toEqual('https://safeweb.norton.com/');
```

My expect keeps saying it is still on the current page, so the click isn't operating.

Answer (score 5):

You might need to *wait until you are on the target page*. There is the relevant [`urlIs` Expected Condition](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorExpectedConditions.prototype.urlIs) added to the Protractor 4:

```
var nortonlink = $('[href*=safeweb]');  // NOTE: also simplified the selector
nortonlink.click();

var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
browser.wait(EC.urlIs("https://safeweb.norton.com/"), 5000);
```

I'm not sure if you need the trailing slash here - try with and without.

Answer (score 1):

Use protractor.ExpectedConditions to check whether link clickable or not. and then click on it.

```
   var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;

   var nortonlink = element(by.css('[href="//safeweb.norton.com/"]'));

   nortonlink.click().then(function(){
   //wait until page completely  loaded
   browser.wait(function () {
       return browser.getCurrentUrl().then(function (url) {
                if(url==!"old url"){       
                return true;
                } });
      }, 8000, 'URL has not changed');

   expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toEqual('https://safeweb.norton.com/');
   });
```

Comment: From what I understand the OP managed to click the link without problems, but the url check expectation failed..

Comment: @alecxe you may be right. I think element is may not  be in clickable status.

Comment: Could be, I would expect the `click()` to fail though in this case. Would be happy to be wrong about it. Thanks.

Comment: The click is working. The new page loads, but the expect fails every time

Comment: @SureshSalloju: Ok, the link is working now, but the expect isn't. It may be because the link is opening in a new tab?

Comment: I understood and implemented browser.wait() see in my code